# Determine this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\right)-\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\right)}{\ln(2n+2)-\ln(2n)}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

how can I determine the following limit? $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\right)-\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\right)}{\ln(2n+2)-\ln(2n)}.$$

This question stems from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235623/is-my-solution-for-divergence-of-int-0-infty-frac-sin10x-ln-x-sqr). The proof presented there is incorrect, and it would be trivial to show that the mentioned integral diverges if the above limit is $>0$ by using the comparison test (anyone feels free to do this by the way).

Comment: Remember... $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln(\frac ab)$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!!

Answer (score 4):

Use l'Hôpital (and some [logarithm identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Using_simpler_operations)) to get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(\frac34 \pi + 2n)-\ln(\frac\pi4+2n)}{\ln(2n+2)-\ln(2n)}
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(3-\frac{16n}{8n+\pi})}{\ln(1+\frac1n)} \\
&\overset{\text{l'Hôpital}}= 16\pi \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(n+1)}{(8n+\pi)(8n+3\pi)} \\
&\overset{\text{linearity of the limit}}=16\pi \bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{8n+\pi}\bigg)\bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{8n+3\pi}\bigg) \\
&= 16\pi\cdot\frac18\cdot\frac18=\frac\pi4.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: That's nice! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using the rules of logarithm so write $$\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\frac{5\pi}{4}+2n}{\frac{\pi}{4}+2n}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{2n+2}{2n}\right)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{3\pi}3+x\right)-\ln\left(\frac\pi3+x\right)$ and $g(x)=\ln(x+2)-\ln x$. Then\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{8 \pi }{(4 x+\pi ) (4 x+3 \pi )}}{-\frac{2}{x^2+2 x}}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4\pi(x^2+2x)}{(4 x+\pi ) (4 x+3 \pi )}\\&=\frac\pi4.\end{align}So, your limit is $\frac\pi4$.

Comment: Thank you! I like it

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n= \frac{\ln\left(\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\right)-\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\right)}{\ln(2n+2)-\ln(2n)}=\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{\pi }{4 n+\frac{\pi }{2}}\right) } {\log \left(1+\frac 1n \right)}$$ Using Taylor expansions
$$a_n=\frac{\frac{\pi }{4 n}-\frac{\pi ^2}{16 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) } {\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) }=\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{(\pi -2) \pi }{16 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Answer (score 1):

This limit can be evaluated by the mean value theorem. Let $f(x)=\ln x$, then because $f(x)$is continuous and differentiable for all $x$,
$$\frac{f(2n+2)-f(2n)}{2} = f'(2n+c_1), 0<c_1<2$$ and $$\frac{f(2n+\frac{3\pi}{4})-f(2n+\frac{\pi}{4}) }{\frac{\pi}{2}}=f'(2n+c_2), 0<c_2<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Since $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\frac{f(2n+2)-f(2n)}{2}}{\frac{f(2n+\frac{3\pi}{4})-f(2n+\frac{\pi}{4}) }{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\cdot \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{2n+c_2}{2n+c_1}\cdot \frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$